# Override datatype of inherited variable (type mixed) to specific type (String)

Tags: php, types

In my code there's an inherited variable that is of `mixed` type. The variable can be either declared as an `Array` or as a `String`. The current implementation looks like this:

```php
abstract class Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    /**
     * The primary key column or columns.
     * A compound key should be declared as an array.
     * You may declare a single-column primary key
     * as a string.
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    protected $_primary = null;

    // ...
}

class MyClass extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    /** @var string */
    protected $_primary = 'PeriodID';

    // ...
}
```

If I now try to access the `$_primary` variable I receive something like this:

```php
// var_dump($this->$_primary);
array(1) {
  [0]=> string(8) "PeriodID"
}
```

However, I would like to just have a `String` and not an `Array` with only one single element?

Can someone tell me, how I can explicitly tell that in `MyClass` `$_primary` is a `String` and not an `Array`?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? I'm unable to replicate the behaviour.

Comment: You are using DocBlocks, FWIW, so the problem is more related to your IDE or linter, not to the PHP interpreter itself. But, even if it were a real PHP type, the type parameter doesn't coerce values for you, it specifies what can be put into in the first place, and I don't know if LSP allow narrowing at a field level. The solution is to access it through a getter which _does_ support narrowing, and/or write to it through a setter that throws if it is not, or cannot be coerced to, a string.